# Put Unity Particle System in Apple Location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity and I'm making a snake game. I have a feature that activates a Particle System when you eat an apple. However, the Particle System is in the middle of the screen but I want it to be where the apple was. Here's my code for where the apple spawn

```
void RandomlyPlacedApple()
    {
        int ran = Random.Range(0, availbleNodes.Count);
        while (isTailNode(availbleNodes[ran]))
        {
            ran = Random.Range(0, availbleNodes.Count);
        }
        PlacePlayerObject(appleObj, availbleNodes[ran].worldPosition);
        appleNode = availbleNodes[ran];
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is if you just **parent your Particle System** to an empty Game Object let's call it for example appleParticles and then instantiate that Game object at the position of the apple.

For example these lines should be in your **Player Script** and should have happen when you **collide with an apple**. For that your player needs a 2D BoxCollider, as well as the apple which needs a 2D Box Collider and you need to set his Tag to "Apple".

After you've added that you can now add this code into your Player Script:

```
  GameObject appleParticles;

  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision col)
    {
        //Check if the object isn't an Apple
        if (!col.CompareTag("Apple"))
           return;
       
       // You spawn the particles at the position of the apple
       Instantiate(appleParticles , apple);
       
       // Starting the particle Effects (You can also let it start automatically when you spawn them in)
       appleParticles.GetComponentInChildren(ParticleSystem).Play();

       // After that destroy the apple, because you ate it
       Destroy(col.gameObject);

       // If you want to destroy the particle system after a certain time as well you can just call
       Destroy(appleParticles, 1f); // 1f means 1 second until it's destroyed
    }
```

Comment: Where do I put all of this? do I put it in the RandomlyPlacedApple or in Start? Also when you say add a particle system to GameObject do you mean like parent it?

Comment: I changed my answer to include all your questions, please check if it helps now.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it however in the instance I try and put my apple in there but it says cannot convert SA.Node to UnityEngine.transform. Also in the GetComponentInChildren is ParticleSystem supposed to be what I named the Empty?

Comment: For your problems you don't need to add a reference to the apple the only thing you do is destroy the gameobject (and instantiate the particles), as long as the Tag of the collided gameobject is "Apple". For the Name no you don't need to do that/shouldn't because you aren't getting the object with the name ParticleSystem. What you are really doing is searching the appleParticles gameobject for a component that has the type ParticleSystem and then getting that.